# VARIANT type punkVal gives undefined values?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, com

I am using few CComVariant type variables to store interface pointers.However, sometime I need to pass interface pointer as NULL.In this case when I do this:

```
CComVariant vAData,vBData;
......
....
CComQIPtr<IBData> pAData = vAData.punkVal; //vAData is {0, VT_I4} when I pass NULL 

CComQIPtr<IBData>pBData = vBData.punkVal;  //vBData is {0, VT_I4} when I pass NULL
```

The first line fails and throws exception since the `vAData.punkVal = 0xffffffff00000000`
But the second line passes fine with no error and it has valid `vBData.punkVal` value(0x0000000000000000).

I am wondering why the two punkVal are different when both are NULL??
Does anybody has any idea why this is happening??
This throws exception only on 64bit machines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`CComVariant` calls `VariantInit()` in constructor and that sets `vt` to `VT_EMPTY`, but leaves `punkVal` uninitialized (doesn't make it null).

What you try to do is therefore undefined behavior since you try to construct a `CComQIPtr` passing it an uninitialized pointer.

If you want a `CComVariant` holding a null `IUnknown*` you can do this:

```
CComVariant variant( static_cast<IUnknown*>( 0 ) ); // null IUnknown*, VT_UNKNOWN type
```

now it's perfectly legal to construct a `CComQIPtr`:

```
CComQIPtr<IWhatever> whatever( variant.punkVal ); //punknVal is null - legal
```

Comment: I am doing something like this:                                  'CComVariant vAData,vBData;
vAData = CComVariant(NULL);vBData = CCOMVariant(NULL);
CComQIPtr<IBData> pAData = vAData.punkVal;
CComQIPtr<IBData>pBData = vBData.punkVal;'                        so the punkval is still remains uninitialize??

Comment: Both the cases the punkval is not initialized but the first line fails and second line gives valid address.

Comment: @Nikhil: "not initialized" means "you get whatever was in memory at that point". Do you really care why one pointer is null and another is not?

Comment: @sharptooth:Does it mean assigning it to NULL,does not warrant that the punkval is initialize to NULL? if not, then what would be the correct way to avoid this problem.

Comment: @Nikhil: What do you want exactly? A VARIANT of type "IUnknown" with a null pointer?

Comment: @sharptooth:I expect that vAData.punkVal will give me a NULL pointer when i initialize the vAData variable with NULL value.

Comment: @Nikhil: Which type VARIANT do you want with a null value?

Comment: @Nikhil: No problem, I added a sample of how to do that.

Comment: @sharptooth:thanks for your quick reply and solution.Also we can check for                                                      'if(S_OK == vAData.ChangeType(VT_UNKNOWN))                         pIAData = vAData.punkVal;'

Answer (score 4):

Some additional information about VARIANTs: they're somewhat weird in that they are compound types: it's basically a union of several types, with the fields for each type (bstrVal, lVal, punkVal, etc) all occupying the same space in memory, and the vt field indicating which field is valid.

You should only attempt to access the field that matches the value of vt. So if vt is VT_BSTR, then only bstrVal is valid; punkVal is off-limits. If vt is VT_I4, then only the lVal field should be used.

VT_EMPTY means "this variant hasn't been set to any value, so doesn't represent anything"; when vt is VT_EMPTY, all fields are off-limits - they might be whatever garbage just happened to be on the stack before - which is what you are seeing here.

In Win64, integers are still 32-bits, but pointers are 64 bits. A variant that is of type VT_I4 with value 0 will have the 32 bits that represent the integer all set to 0, but the rest of the memory in the variant could be any leftover garbage. If you try to treat that memory as a 64-bit pointer - by accessing punkVal - then you'll end up with a pointer made from those 32 0 bits, but also from an adjacent 32bits that have never been properly initialized - that's likely why you're seeing differences between the two cases here.

In Win32, you get lucky: the pointer is the same size as the int, so if you access a VT_I4 that's 0 and read the punkVal (which you shouldn't!), you would end up getting a NULL pointer in that case.